# Why don't we have notification for a comment with 10+ upvotes?

Tags: feature-request

I love the way ELL comes up with gamification. While we have such lovely notifications for upvote, popular question, good question, good answer and so on, we lack one important thing, I think.

Why don't we have a notification for a comment that received more than 10 upvotes? I see that after certain number of upvotes, the 'color' of the 'number of upvotes' changes.

Why am I advocating this?

Because, at times, we have comments that are better than answers! And, even if they are not, they provide very good insight. We must appreciate this and send notification to the commenter.

Even further, we can have the badge like...

> point-out (10 or more comments with 10 upvotes) 
>  tidbit (5 or more comments with 10 upvotes) 
>  comment-smith (Comment with 20 or more upvotes) 
>  and so on...

Comment: Well, Maulik I'm trying really hard to figure out why you didn't post this in meta.SE (no, not really, they advocate *per site meta first, meta.SE second*) but what good would this do, other than **gamification**? Also, you can run [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution) and [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/296079/top-comment-votes-again) among others to figure out all you want about comments.

Comment: FYI, under "participation badges", there is a Pundit badge for "Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more". So far only 15 people have earned it on all of ELL.

Comment: I know this is an older post (I found it when I was looking through the moderator nominations), but it inspired me to write a quick [query to list a user's highest rated comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/355425/top-rated-comments-for-a-user).

Comment: wow @ColleenV that is so wonderful. I accept your 'thanks'! haha!